# How to group consecutive column values separated by value (np.nan)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I got the following `pandas.DataFrame` where the column `value` is the input data and `group` is the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0.1, 0.2, np.nan, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, np.nan, 0.1], 
                   'group': [1, 1, np.nan, 2, 2, 2, np.nan, 3]})
```

I would like to assign a unique ID for each segment of consecutive numbers, which are separated by np.nan. I might need some clustering approach for this, but I could not find any pandas function to achieve this yet.

Comment: There are always only one NaN row? not 2 consecutive?

Comment: There could also be more than 1, even like a series of 100+ in a row. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea working if multiple consecutive missing values - use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for create groups with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
m = df['value'].isna()
df.loc[~m, 'g'] = pd.factorize(m.cumsum()[~m])[0]+ 1
print (df)
   value  group    g
0    0.1    1.0  1.0
1    0.2    1.0  1.0
2    NaN    NaN  NaN
3    0.2    2.0  2.0
4    0.3    2.0  2.0
5    NaN    NaN  NaN
6    NaN    NaN  NaN
7    0.1    3.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We should drop duplicates consecutive repeated NaNs to be able to create the groups with [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

```
m = df.isna().any(axis=1).loc[lambda x: ~(x & x.shift(-1))]
df['group'] = m.cumsum().add(1).mask(m)

# output @jezrael sample
print(df)

   value  group
0    0.1    1.0
1    0.2    1.0
2    NaN    NaN
3    0.2    2.0
4    0.3    2.0
5    NaN    NaN
6    NaN    NaN
7    0.1    3.0
```